# Xib file access parents Outlet

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I'm trying to access UIScrollView that's in UIViewController via xib file. I have 3 xib files that are placed in main ViewController and controlled with ScrollView. I want to access ScrollView from my xib (.swift) file. I tried this:

MyViewControler.swift

```
@IBOutlet var ScrollView: UIScrollView!
func ScrolToRight(){
    ScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.width, y: 0), animated: false)
}
```

XibFile.swift

```
MyViewControler().ScrolToRight()
```

but every time i try calling function from XibFile.swift UIScrollView is nill and the app crashes. I can't figure out why is it nill since it's declared in interface builder and with outlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since ScrollView is a IBOutlet, it will be nil if you instantiate "MyViewController" like MyViewController().

You should be instantiating it either through storyboard or XIB.

Comment: I ended up using one .swift with multiple classes in it, and global var ScrollView.

Comment: That is OK. But IBOutlets get initialized only when the controller is instantiated through storyboard or XIB